# Estimate the p-value for a sample of size N to come from a normal distribution by using both sample and population mean/stdev

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Is there a way to check if a sample of size N (e.g. 30) comes from a normal distribution with a known population mean and standard deviation? I'd like to use all the information available (the sample mean and standard deviation and the population mean and standard deviation) in the test.

My understanding is that the t-test is using the sample standard deviation and the z-test is using the population standard deviation. I have both standard deviations available and my limited understanding is that using more information in the test would give a better estimate.